# Is it more efficient to iterate often or process intensive?

Tags: performance, batch-file, iteration

I have a lot of text processing scripts to apply on a lot of text files. I am writing a batch script (on Win 7) to start them and to iterate through the directories and subdirectories containing the text files. Actually, I am wondering if there is a preferable way of iterating more often or executing more processes during one iteration regarding efficieny:

**Variant A**

```
for x in y
process 1 on x
process 2 on x 
process 3 on x
```

or **Variant B**

```
for x in y
process 1 on x

for x in y
process 2 on x

for x in y
process 3 on x
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Comment, as this is just an opinion. Without more information, first approach should make better use of the filesystem cache.

Comment: A `for /f` loop also has a bug when a very large number of files/long filenames are processed which causes long delays.  The details of the task are important to give you an answer because a regular `for` loop will also process incorrectly in certain cases.  The best way to process tasks in batch scripts, so often depends on the actual task.

Answer (score 1):

That fully depends on the size of your loop, the amount of processes and the resources required by those processes (and the programming language you use ofcourse ;))
Best way to figure this out is by creating a test script, give both methods a go and see whitch is the fastest.

If the difference is small, I would go with the cleanest solution, only use 1 loop executing multiple processes... just becuase it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on several factors, so no answer will be definitive.  However I think the approach you take will primarily depend on what the processing is that you're doing.

Lets say that `process1` alters its input, as does `process2` and `process3`.  If possible you could write the processing so that they can take `stdin`, process it, and provide output to `stdout` - that way you could do:

```
for each x in y do
  process1 x | process2 | process3 > x_new
  overwrite x with x_new
```

Each file only gets read in once, piped through all processes to "do their thing", and replaced at the end.

But as I said, this depends entirely on what the processing actually does.